# Reversing a string in perl without using "reverse" function

Tags: regex, string, perl

I was looking for clues on how to reverse a string in Perl without using the builtin `reverse` function and came across the following piece of code for reversing $str.

```
print +($str =~ /./g)[-$_] for (1 .. $#{[$str =~ /./g]} + 1);
```

I was trying to understand how this works a bit more and expanded the above code to something like this.

```
for (1 .. $#{[$str =~ /./g]} + 1) {
   $rev_str_1 = ($str =~ /./g)[-$_];   
   print $rev_str_1;   
}
```

The above code snippet also works fine. But, the problem comes when I add any print inside the `for` loop to understand how the string manipulation is working.

```
for (1 .. $#{[$str =~ /./g]} + 1) {
   $rev_str_1 = ($str =~ /./g)[-$_];   
   print "\nin loop now ";
   print $rev_str_1;   
}
```

For input string of `stressed`, following is the output for above code

```
in loop now d
in loop now e
in loop now s
in loop now s
in loop now e
in loop now r
in loop now t
in loop now s
```

It seems like the entire string reversal is happening in this part `($str =~ /./g)[-$_]` but I am trying to understand why is it not working when I add an extra print. Appreciate any pointers.

Comment: What do you mean by _it is not working when I add an extra `print`_.?

Comment: There's no reason not to use the `reverse` function. It's part of perl. Every version of perl has it. Avoiding `reverse` makes your code harder to read.

Comment: Thanks for inputs. I should have been clearer. What I mean is that, with the following code piece `for (1 .. $#{[$str =~ /./g]} + 1) {
   $rev_str_1 = ($str =~ /./g)[-$_];   
   print $rev_str_1;   
}`, the output of this program is _desserts_ as expected. But with the second code piece I had posted earlier, it never prints _desserts_. The input string is _stressed_ for both.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're assuming that the string is reversed before being printed, but the program just prints all the characters in the string one at a time in reverse order

Here's how it works

It's based around the expression `$str =~ /./g` which uses a global regex match with a pattern that matches any single character. In list context it returns all the characters in the string as a list. Note that a dot `.` without the `/s` pattern modifier doesn't match linefeed. That's a bug, but probably isn't critical in this situation

This expression

```
$#{ [ $str =~ /./g ] } + 1
```

creates an anonymous array of the characters in `$str` with `[ $str =~ /./g ]`. Then uses `$#` to get the index of the last element of the array, and adds 1 to get the total number of characters (because the index is zero-based). So the loop is executing with `$_` in the range 1 to the number of characters in `$str`. This is unnecessarily obscure and should probably be written `1 .. length($str)` except for the special case of linefeed characters mentioned above

The body of the loop uses `($str =~ /./g)[-$_]`, which splits `$str` into characters again in the same way as before, and then uses the fact that negative indexes in Perl refer to elements relative to the *end* of the array or list. So the last character in `$str` is at index -1, the second to last at index -2 and so on. Again, this is unnecessarily arcane; the expression is exactly equivalent to `substr($str, -$_, 1)`, again with the exception that the regex version ignores linefeed characters

Printing the characters one at a time like this results in `$str` being printed in reverse

It may be easier to understand if the string is split into a real array, and the reversed string is accumulated into a buffer, like this

```
my $reverse = '';
my @str = $str =~ /./sg;
for ( 1 .. @str ) {
    $reverse .= $str[-$_];
}

print $reverse, "\n";
```

Or, using `length` and `substr` as described above, this is equivalent to

```
my $reverse = '';
$reverse .= substr($str, -$_, 1) for 1 .. length($str);
print $reverse, "\n";
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. It does explain what is going on in the background. One more question though. With this code snippet `use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = "stressed";
my $rev_str_1;

for (1 .. $#{[$str =~ /./g]} + 1) {
   $rev_str_1 = ($str =~ /./g)[-$_];   
   print $rev_str_1;   
}`,  the output is `desserts`. When I change the code to this `use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = "stressed";
my $rev_str_1;

for (1 .. $#{[$str =~ /./g]} + 1) {
   $rev_str_1 = ($str =~ /./g)[-$_];   
   print $rev_str_1;   
   print "Loop Variable is $_\n";
}`,

Comment: the output is something like this `dLoop Variable is 1
eLoop Variable is 2
sLoop Variable is 3
sLoop Variable is 4
eLoop Variable is 5
rLoop Variable is 6
tLoop Variable is 7
sLoop Variable is 8
`.  How is it that the `print` inside the `for` loop is changing the behavior of string reversal?